# How to set callback page and redirct_uri for file picker

Tags: javascript, onedrive, filepicker

I'm newbie with OneDrive API and using Microsoft OneDrive file picker for one web-app using javascript and while using WL.init(), it asks for Client_Id and Redirect_UI. I've created Client_Id using Live SDK app management site and added Redirect_UI as 'http://www.onedrivefilepicker.com/callback.aspx'; where 'onedrivefilepicker' is name of my application and callback.aspx is just a blank page created.
 But, while running the website, it shows error "The server at www.onedrivefilepicker.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. "
I understand this error, but don't know how to set redirect_uri and callback page. Please guide me.

Dipti

*[EDITED]*
Code is as follows:

I'm posting my code as follows:

```
WL.init({client_id: "00000000XXXXXXXX", 
redirect_uri:"http://www.OneDriveFilePicker.com/Callback.aspx",
  });
    function uploadFile_fileDialog() {
        WL.fileDialog({mode: "save" }).then(
         function (response) {
           WL.upload({
             path: response.data.folders[0].id,
             element: "file",
             overwrite: "rename"
         }).then(
            function (response) {document.getElementById("info").innerText = "File uploaded.";
      },
         function (responseFailed) {document.getElementById("info").innerText =
        "Error uploading file: " + responseFailed.error.message; 
              } ); },
       function (responseFailed) {
           document.getElementById("info").innerText =
                    "Error getting folder info: " + responseFailed.error.message;
            }
        );
    }
```

Following is the **HTML**:

```
 <button onclick="uploadFile_fileDialog()">Save file with OneDrive file picker</button>
 <label id="info"></label>
```

Comment: its error about your deployment, DNS is naming server directory.. Client is unable to ping on the server..
Show what have you done so that able to guide you.

Comment: I'm posting my code as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Correct code on redirect_URI as

```
redirect_uri:"http://www.onedrivefilepicker.com/callback.aspx"
```

Hopefully it works for you in DNS lookup issue.

Comment: still same error. One more thing, should any code be added to callback.aspx page?

Comment: can you show callback.aspx page code, if is there any code?
and link of the article which you refer to do this thing..

Comment: callback.aspx page is just an empty page, I've just added <b> <script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script></b> in the <b><head></head> </b> section of the page. I'm referring to following link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659733.aspx]

Comment: do check your JS and JSON responses in according to this article.